# How to get a customized page numbering

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, page-numbering

I need a special numbering schema for the pages of a document. Given arbitrary integers n and k (with k different from 0 and from 1), the first (logical) page must be numbered n and subsequent (logical) pages must be numbered n+k,n+2k,n+3k,...

So, for example, for n=10 and k=-3 the pages of a document must be numbered 10,7,4,1,-2,-5,-8,...

The solution must be compatible with `hyperref`'s `\ref`, `\pageref`, and similar commands, and must also produce the correct values in lists such as ToC, LoF, and LoT.

Ideally, the numbering must be obtained by invoking a command `\numberingschema{<initial value>}{<step>}`.

Comment: Great to see you again! I hope you are well! I missed your great beamer answers!

Comment: @samcarter I am well, thank you! I see you are doing a fine job answering `beamer` questions.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Even if you do not know you personally I make you my compliments for your skill and your professionalism. The LaTeX users have always written well of you. My best regards.

Answer (score 7):

The following might be sufficient for content being set within the document - `\thepage` is used in the footer as well as the ToC, and therefore includes an expandable calculation based on the `\initpage` and `\pagestep`. An additional `pageschema` is introduced to allow for multiple schemas in one document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xfp,regexpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example

\newcounter{pageschema}\renewcommand{\thepageschema}{\alph{pageschema}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\fpeval{\initpage+\pagestep*(\value{page}-1)}}

\newcommand{\pagenumberingschema}[2]{%
  \clearpage
  \stepcounter{pageschema}% New page schema
  \def\initpage{#1}% Store initial page value
  \def\pagestep{#2}% Store page step
  \setcounter{page}{1}% New page schema start
  \ignorespaces
  }
\AtBeginDocument{\pagenumberingschema{1}{1}}% Initialize page numbering schema

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% Update the hyperlink anchors to include page schema
\xpatchcmd*{\Hy@EveryPageAnchor}{page.}{page.\thepageschema.}{}{}
\makeatother

\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\section{First page schema}
\lipsum[1-10]

\pagenumberingschema{7}{-3}
\section{Second page schema A}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Second page schema B}
\lipsum[21-40]
\section{Second page schema C}
\lipsum[41-50]

\pagenumberingschema{7}{17}
\section{Third page schema A}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Third page schema B}
\lipsum[21-40]
\section{Third page schema C}
\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

Updates to the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) page anchors ensure that PDF links are OK. Also, a forced `\clearpage` is inserted as part of the `\pagenumberingschema`, which seems a logical requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Nice problem. I have assumed it is enough to set `\thepage` since that is used in refs. It seems to work at least after loading `hyperref` but I have not tested it much more (I am a bit unsure about that part).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcount\ncnt
\newcount\kcnt
\def\numberingschema#1#2{%{<initial value>}{<step>}
  \ncnt=#1
  \kcnt=#2
  \c@page=0
}
\def\thepage{\@arabic{\numexpr \ncnt+\c@page*\kcnt\relax}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\numberingschema{5}{-3}
\tableofcontents

\section{Just a section to separate from TOC}
See Section \ref{sec:2} on page \pageref{sec:2} or Section \ref{sec:2-2} on page \pageref{sec:2-2}
\newpage 

\section{First section}
\label{sec:1}
\newpage


\section{Second section}
\label{sec:2}
\newpage

\section{Third section}
\label{sec:3}
\newpage

\section{Forth section}
\label{sec:4}
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\numberingschema{25}{17}
\section{Second First section}
\label{sec:2-1}
\newpage

\section{Second Second section}
\label{sec:2-2}
\newpage

\section{Second Third section}
\label{sec:2-3}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work as expected as soon as you have a duplicate page number within the document. That is, add another "section" at the bottom using `\numberingschema{5}{-3}` again (say). The reason? `\thepage` outputs the same number, which is used in the PDF as an anchor... and duplicate anchors cause hyperlink problems.

Comment: @Werner, I see your point. To be honest I don't know much about the internals of `hyperref`. But I did some tests, e.g. the one you said in your comment. The links from ToC to the sections, as well as the links from references in the text, seems to work in the pdf. So even if I have two pages `-1` the links from the ToC ends up on the correct pages.

Comment: You should test them from the PDF bookmarks. And you'll see the duplicate destination warnings in the `.log`.

Comment: @Werner: Ah, I actually suspected there were something more to it. I have found the warnings, but I cannot detect any flaws from the pdf reader. It works fine both from the document and the bookmarks.

Comment: @Werner: On the positive side, I think it works as long as there are no duplicate page numbers. And duplicate page numbers can not be considered good typesetting. (Whereas, of course, the suggested page numbering scheme should be considered good typesetting;-)